# Laravel project not run by php artisan serve command

Tags: laravel

error when run php artisan serve command

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\crm>php artisan serve
```

In Connection.php line 647:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'crm.clients' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `clients` where exists (select * from `followups` where `clients`.`id` = `followups`.`client_id` and `followup` = TBRO and date(`date`) = 2018-02-18))
```

In Connection.php line 319:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'crm.clients' doesn't exist
```

Comment: Have you run `php artisan migrate` before hand?

Comment: the same error when php artisan migrate command

Answer (score 0):

the trouble seem to be that you don't have the table created. Have you ran the migrate command?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you have to first update your composer by this command.
**composer update**

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you to check your db if there is a db called crm in the case you are in a MySQL environment and also check your connection to the database in the config/database or in the .env . It seems that you cannot create the table with the migrate command and since you doesn’t have the tables the serve command report an error.

Comment: i crated manually table.. then no error run successfuully but run migrate commmand throw same error

Comment: The user that you use with laravel is authorized to access the dB?